# How to prove (without differentiation) that $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^{\frac{1}{2n}}$ is strictly monotonically decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $f(n) = n^{\frac{1}{2n}}$.
>
> Prove the existence of an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n) > f(n+1) \forall n \geq n_0$ and find its smallest possible value.

None of my attempts to solve this problem, namely a proof by induction and a proof by contradiction, have been fruitful. However, I did find that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (f(n)) = 1$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) = 0$.

What's an appropriate approach to prove the statement, ideally without the use of derivatives?

Comment: Can you use differentiation?

Comment: Same as showing $(1/(2n))\ln n$ is eventually decreasing. Take the derivative.

Comment: Differentiation has not been introduced to us as of yet.

Comment: @StckXchnge-nub12 You should include in the question that you can't use differentiation, because the question is much easier with it allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quite elementary way is as follows:

- Note that $x^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing.
- $\Rightarrow$ It is enough to show $n^\frac{1}{n}> (n+1)^\frac{1}{n+1}$ from a certain $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ on

You have
$$n^\frac{1}{n}> (n+1)^\frac{1}{n+1} \Leftrightarrow n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$$
$$\Leftrightarrow n > \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$

You either know that the expression on the RHS approaches $e$ from below or you show it for $n\geq n_0=3$ using the binomial expansion:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n=1+1+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}$$ $$\leq 2+ \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}< 2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}=3$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why one can completely disregard $\sqrt{x}$ given it's strictly increasing? After all, it does greatly diminish the growth in the base, while $\frac{1}{n}$ can grow smaller without further hindrance, thus diminishing the resulting number to a relatively great degree. I.e., inituitively, I believe $\frac{1}{n}$ grows small faster than $\sqrt{x}$ does grow big. Additionally, what exactly happened in the step $n^\frac{1}{n}> (n+1)^\frac{1}{n+1} \Leftrightarrow n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$?

Comment: @StckXchnge-nub12 : Will answer quickly.

Comment: Concerning the root: We have for $0<x,y$ always $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y} \Leftrightarrow x<y$. This is so because $y-x = (\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x})$. So, showing $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}$ is equivalent to showing $x<y$.

Comment: In the other step I raise both sides of the inequality to the power of $n(n+1)$. Here, I use that for $0<x,y $ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x<y \Leftrightarrow x^m < y^m$.

Answer (score 1):

That is  because the function $f(x)=x^{\tfrac 1{2x}}$ is ultimately decreasing. To prove it, observe it is equivalent to proving it for the function $\;g(x)=\ln(f(x))=\dfrac1{2x}\ln x$. Now 
$$g'(x)=\frac 12\biggl(-\frac1{x^2}\ln x+\frac1{x^2}\biggr)=\frac{1-\ln x}{2x^2}.$$
Do you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

> In this development, we forgo the use of calculus and rely on elementary analysis only.  We now proceed.

---

Let $a_n=n^{1/2n}$.  To show that $a_n$ is decreasing, it suffices to show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$.  This is equivalent to our showing that $2\log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=\log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^2<0$.

Using $\log(x)\le x-1$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)^2&=\frac1{n+1}\log(n+1)-\frac1{n}\log(n)\\\\
&=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left(n\log(n+1)-(n+1)\log(n) \right)\\\\
&=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left(n\log(n)+n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-(n+1)\log(n) \right)\\\\
&=\frac1{n(n+1)}\left(n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\log(n) \right)\\\\
&\le \frac1{n(n+1)}\left(1-\log(n) \right)\\\\
&<0
\end{align}$$

whenever $\log(n)>1$.  This occurs whenever $n>3>e$.  And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2x}}=e^{\frac{\log{x}}{2x}}$ is  strictly decreasing if $x>e$.

You can prove this by differentiation.

So  $n=  [e]+1$ is the minimun.

Here $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$

Comment: And how exactly do you find that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $x > e$?

Comment: @StckXchnge-nub12 I edited my answer.